# Is it possible to configure Eclipse to do ctrl+space always like sts 3.3.0 does

Tags: eclipse, spring, suite

Spring tool suite v3.3.0 does ctrl+space action automaticly after every typed character. It gives coding speed. Is it possible to configure Eclipse Juno Service Release 2, to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Eclipse preferences, go to Java > Editor > Content Assist. In the Auto Activation group, in the the Auto Activation triggers for Java add  all the letters and space after the dot.

You can also reduce the activation delay. I have set mine to 50ms for instance.

I think it should give you most of what you expect. Note that I have never used STS.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That option default value is set to ".", needed to change it: "_.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and it works fine.